# What is the word used to describe a forced choice

Tags: phrase-requests, british-english

I am looking for a word to describe a certain situation where you must choose one  option or the other, as in *it's either me or her.*

For example:

> If you stay friends with her we can't be in a relationship, but if you're not friends with her then we can stay a couple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're probably looking for ***ultimatum:***

> A final demand or statement of terms, the rejection of which will result in retaliation or a breakdown in relations:
>   *their employers issued an ultimatum demanding an immediate return to work*
>
> [[ODO]](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ultimatum)

It's derived from Latin *ultimus/-a/-um:* final, furthest.

Comment: This does not answer the question, IMO, although it does express forcing. There is nothing in *ultimatum* that expresses the obligation of **choosing** between alternatives. (Presumably the choice asked about is not just the "choice" of accepting or rejecting an ultimatum.)

Answer (score 3):

But the person who receives an *ultimatum* now faces a *dilemma*.

Answer (score 0):

What they are describing is a false dichotomy, lol.